# OpenVPN cannot ping

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have configured OVPN server on Mikrotik router.

My LAN have adresses: 192.168.0.0/24
I have set vpn local address to: 192.168.1.5 and remote address 192.168.1.6
Router on which VPN server is runing has ip 192.168.0.30

The problem is that I can only ping 192.168.0.30 and 192.168.1.5 (local vpn address). I cannot ping other devices in network.

In firewall rules I have:

- accept chain:input; protocol: tcp; dst. port 1723
- accept chain: input/output/forward; src: 192.168.1.5

In routes I have set:

- dst.: 192.168.0.0/24 with gateway ovpn-test

I am not very familiar with networking and linux systems so every suggestion how to improve this question and provide more details is also welcomed.

My client script:

```
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote xx.xx.xx.xx 11723

ca ca.crt
key picom.key
cert picom.crt

tls-client
port 11723

persist-tun
persist-key

verb 3
auth SHA1
pull
auth-user-pass

route-method exe
route-delay 2

route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

[image: screen]

Edit:

1. Router IP address is 192.168.0.30
2. VPN server local address is 192.168.1.5
3. Remote address is 192.168.1.6
4. VPN client gets address 192.168.1.6. I don't know if I understand this question right?
5. VPN client is connected to different network using another ISP
6. Port 11723 in router which has external IP is forwarded to 1723 of my router   with VPN server. Unfortunately I dont have access to this router config.

[image: screen]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is need to set NAT masquarade for srcnat chain with 192.168.1.0 (OpenVPN  as a source address.

Comment: Not if you've set up the routing like I've been trying to describe

Comment: VPN's LAN address is 192.168.1.6. I've added route as you can see on attached screen and it does not work. If you can explain it more clearly I would be grateful.

Comment: The LAN address of the VPN Server is not 192.168.1.anything. It is 192.168.0.something. The router doesn't know 192.168.1. You route that via the **LAN** address of your VPN Server

Comment: As I have written VPN local address is 192.168.1.5, remote address is 192.168.1.6. Tracert gives only 192.168.1.5->192.168.0.1. I don't see any other vpn server address in router configuration.

Comment: You CANNOT have 192.168.1.anything as your LAN address. Please listen to what I'm telling you. Your LAN addresses start 192.168.0 **not** 192.168.1.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I couldn't find a way to check what is vpn server address. I have tried router address -> gateway unreachable, I have tried tracert to find out but as you see above I've failed...

Comment: In your own question you state that your VPN server address is 192.168.0.6. It is this address you give to your router for routing the 192.168.1 network

Comment: Previously I have set VPN remote address to 192.168.0.6 then I've changed to 192.168.1.6 (after your answer, question is edited as you see). But if there is any other address between 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.0.1 wouldn't it be shown in tracert?

Comment: The LAN addresses are 192.168.0.*. The VPN Server and Client addresses are 192.168.1.*. Your VPN Server has two addresses: one for the LAN and one for the VPN.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so the problem is now how to check VPN Server LAN address. I've tried as you said 192.168.0.30 (router address) in routing but it says that the gateway is not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same network address range in two distinct places.

1. Your LAN is 192.168.0.0/24. No other addresses must be used on the LAN itself.
2. Your OpenVPN route must not be 192.168.0/24. Use addresses 192.168.1.0/24 or indeed from any other RFC1918 address. But not 192.168.0.0/24.
3. If you are going to set up a static route on your Router to the VPN Server for the VPN subnet 192.168.1.0/24 you must reference the VPN Server with its LAN address 192.168.0.30 (see point #1).

You will also probably need to enable forwarding. To test (until the next reboot) that this works you can run

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Once you're happy you can add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` into the system file `/etc/sysctl.conf` or create your own file under `/etc/sysctl.d/`. You may find the line already present but just commented out. Obviously in this case you could just uncomment the line.

I see from the comments that you've added a route from your clients to the LAN. Don't forget the reverse entry for your LAN clients back to the VPN.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use OpenVPN address from LAN range? If I do so, I couldn't ping even a router. How to make route for LAN? What should be set in openvpn local address, remote address and route?

Comment: I've added: route 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 and route 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 to client config file and I can ping router again but still no other devices

Comment: What do you mean reverse entry for LAN clients back to the VPN?

Comment: The devices on your LAN only have a default route via your router. If this router is your OpenVPN endpoint then you're ok, because it will know where to send packets. Otherwise you will have to put explicit routes in either your router or all your LAN clients so that they know where to send 192.168.1.0/24 traffic.

Comment: I have ipforwarding and added route in router: dst: 192.168.1.6; gateway: <openvpn> pref-source: 192.168.0.1 and still could not ping 192.168.0.1

Comment: @krzych OK. Please update your question to include this information: 1. Your router's IP address. 2. Your OpenVPN server's IP address on the LAN. 3. Your OpenVPN server's IP address for its VPN clients. 4. An configured example of a VPN client IP address. 5. Please also confirm that your VPN client isn't connected to your LAN but that it can reach the OpenVPN server. (Some of this information you'll have already provided, I know.) 6. Please check what you have written in your question for the port in your `iptables` firewall rules as the port number doesn't match your OpenVPN configuration

Comment: Thanks for suggestions I have updated question. Hope that I've provided all informations clear.

Comment: @krzych the configuration is still not quite right. In the comments above you write, "_I have ipforwarding and added route in router..._". The router needs a route for the network 192.168.1.0/24 via the VPN Server's LAN address, which I believe is 192.168.0.30. You must only have 192.168.0 addresses on your LAN and only 192.168.1 addresses for your VPN.

Comment: I have this route. I have added screen from routes. The gateway for route is open-vpn address